# HTML Video currentTime not being set correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I have a video being used as a background of a mobile device to show a reactive animation for when the phone is rotated its works (sort of) but when the rotation requires it to loop from start to end or end to start it does not loop and I have no clue why as the value it's trying to be set as should work.

this is the function that subscribes to the gyroscope and updates the angle with some maths

```
    this.gyroscope.watch(this.options)
    .subscribe((orientation: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
        // need delta time to correctly calculate angle per update
        this.time.now = new Date().getTime();
        this.time.delta = this.time.now - this.time.last;

        if (this.videoLoaded) {

            // convert radians/sec to degree/sec and times by deltaTime
            const degree = 180 / Math.PI * orientation.z;
            this.targetAngle -= (this.time.delta / 1000) * degree;

            // lerp target angle no clipping applied
            this.angle = (1 - .1) * this.angle + .1 * this.targetAngle;

            // convert lerped angle into clipped 0-360
            let displayAngle = this.angle % 360;
            if (displayAngle < 0) { displayAngle = 360 + displayAngle; }

            // convert angle to time of video round to tenths dec
            this.frame = Math.round((displayAngle * this.axeVideo.duration / 360) * 10) / 10;

            // set video time
            this.axeVideo.currentTime = this.frame;
        } else {
            // clear angle as gyro spits out large values at first
            this.angle = this.targetAngle = 0;
        }
        // update last time for deltaTime calc
        this.time.last = this.time.now;
    });
```

this is all correct maths and logically works however when testing the video is going to either edge and locking up no matter how many rotations the phone does and to "unlock" it i must rotate the phone back the same amount.

[Screen Capture of issue](https://streamable.com/tgmdb) recording is a little laggy but normally super smooth (hence why i use this solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `ion-range` that has [(ngModel)] on it overriding the set time.